# Error inserting new rows (foreign key issue) in SQL 

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I am trying to debug some classic ASP code and the app keeps breaking on an insert statement. The backend is in SQL

The statement looks something like this:

```
insert into tableX (id, fo, ao) values (12, '', 'ab')
```

in `tableX` both `fo` and `ao` are set to allow null values.

`fo` is a foreign key pointing to the `foTable` (look up table)

I guess it's not liking the single quotes? How else do I go about this in classic asp?

The error I'm getting is:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_tableX_FO". The conflict occurred in database "tableX", table
>   "dbo.FIELD_OFFICE", column 'FO'.

I also want to add that this is a process of migrating from Oracle. Does anyone know if Oracle treats '' as nulls, which is why I'm now getting an error in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty string is not a null value. You need to call it like this

```
insert into tableX (id, fo, ao) values (12, null, 'ab')
```

Alternatively

```
insert into tableX (id, ao) values (12, 'ab')
```

Comment: this is a process of migrating from Oracle. do you know if oracle treats '' as nulls, which is my i'm now getting an error in SQL?

Comment: Yes, empty strings are treated as null values in Oracle, but not in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these statements will work.

```
insert into tableX (id, ao) values (12, 'ab')
```

or

```
insert into tableX (id, fo, ao) values (12, NULL, 'ab')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `fo` is set to allow nulls and you don't want to violate the FK constraint, then you should  provide `NULL` instead of an empty string for the `fo` column.